Shouldn't references in a Rust iterator be dropped along with the iterator?
I am confused about the nature of lifetimes (and lifetime generics) in Rust after solving the Exercism "Xorcism" exercise. I have been working with the assumption that the ownership system means that if an item that contains a reference, the reference is dropped with it?
I have been programming in Rust for a little while, have read the Rust book (and other resources) but I cannot find anything that explains this behavior. Of course it's possible that I missed something, I would greatly appreciate any resources that could help me understand this behavior and expect it in the future.
In short, the exercise is a simple exercise that involves xor-ing input bytes with a stored key. Part of the exercise is making a function that adapts a collection of bytes into an iterator of xor-ed bytes:
pub struct Xorcism<'a> {
    key: &'a [u8],
    cur: usize,
}

impl<'a> Xorcism<'a> {
    // other functions

    pub fn munge<'b, Data>(&'b mut self, data: Data) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 'b
    where
        Data: IntoIterator + 'b,
        Data::Item: Borrow<u8>,
    {
        data.into_iter().map(|byte| {
            let xored = self.key[self.cur] ^ byte.borrow();
            self.cur += 1;
            self.cur %= self.key.len();
            xored
        })
    }
}

The problem is in this test:
    // other code
    let key = &[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let input = &[0b1010_1010, 0b0101_0101];

    let mut xs = Xorcism::new(&key);
    let out1: Vec<u8> = xs.munge(input).collect();
    let out2: Vec<u8> = xs.munge(input).collect();
    let out3: Vec<u8> = xs.munge(input).collect();
    let out4: Vec<u8> = xs.munge(input).collect();
    let out5: Vec<u8> = xs.munge(input).collect();
    // other code

If I remove the 'b lifetime, and annotate the munge function with 'a:
    pub fn munge<Data>(&'a mut self, data: Data) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a
    where
        Data: IntoIterator + 'a,

I get an E0499 error about multiple mutable references:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `xs` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> tests/xorcism.rs:68:24
   |
67 |     let out1: Vec<_> = xs.munge(input).collect();
   |                        -- first mutable borrow occurs here
68 |     let out2: Vec<_> = xs.munge(input).collect();
   |                        ^^
   |                        |
   |                        second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        first borrow later used here

In theory, I understand that the purpose of the 'b lifetime is to coerce &mut self to be of the shorter lifetime of the returned impl Iterator, however what I don't understand is:
Shouldn't collect() cause the returned iterator to be dropped from memory? collect() takes ownership of self and then returns a Vec<u8> (which contains no references to Xorcism), I do not understand why the mutable reference is still valid.

Reusing lifetimes is often (not always) wrong. By reusing the 'a lifetime, you've created an unnecessary constraint that you now must follow. In particular, &'a mut T<'a> is always wrong, and means that the value can only be used once, and this is what you have here.

@ChayimFriedman so regardless of what else happens in the function &'a mut T<'a> will exist for as long as 'a (therefore not being able to be used again)? That would explain the error, but it feels a little counter intuitive.

When the compiler borrow-checks a function call, it never looks inside the function, only at its signature. You have defined the signature wrongly, so it thinks it borrows something while in reality it doesn't.

When you say it like that, it is very simple. The compiler is assuming that that reference lives despite the fact that in reality it doesn't.
Thanks a ton, if you would like to submit that as an answer I'll accept it
